# Ruby on Rails 'pg' gem installation error Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rubygems

does anyone know why the error

> "ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
>
> Permission denied @ rb_sysopen -
> C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.3-x64-mingw32/lib/2.7/pg_ext.so"

appears while trying to install pg gem in Windows 10?
I tried running gem install pg with admin privileges in command prompt in my application folder, but it throws this error.. I also checked out site https://rubygems.org/gems/pg and there copied how to install pg via command line, and what to include in Gemfile.
Here is my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

# ruby '2.5.7'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.4'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
# gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'coffee-script-source'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.4.1'

# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
gem 'rack-attack'
gem 'rack-cors'
gem 'jwt'
# gem 'acts_as_paranoid', '~> 0.6.0'
gem 'active_model_serializers'
gem 'pagy'
gem 'pager_api'
gem "pundit"
gem "administrate", git: "https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate"
gem "figaro"
gem 'faker'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'fog-aws'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
  gem "pry"
end

group :development do
gem 'tzinfo-data'
gem 'annotate'
gem 'listen'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
# gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem "auth0", "~> 5.0"
```

Thank you very much reading this. (p.s. i am pretty new at ruby on rails, and so far i did 2 apps where i haven't used pg gem, installation of other gems all went well :/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you've downloaded and installed PostgreSQL on your system. Use the following to point the gem to where postgres is installed. This is an example of what it'd look like on my system.

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config='C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin\pg_config.exe'
```